# Is there a way to increase remote query timeout for SQL Azure without increasing DTUs?

Tags: ssis, azure-sql-database, timeoutexception

I get a timeout selecting rows in my SSIS package... (Complete error details below).

- The query runs for 3mins in SSMS.
- My SQL Azure Server has a Standard1 scale (20DTUs).
- Time elapsed is always 30seconds.
- I did fix the "Connect Timeout" and set a value of 300 (5mins)
- I cannot run

  EXEC sp_configure 'remote query timeout', 300 ;

  because it's a SQL Azure.

Aside from increasing DTUs, is there a way to extend the remote connection to the azure server?
My only purpose is to run some big queries on SSIS once in a while...

> Error: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation timed out
>     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
>     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
>     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
>     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption)
>     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
>     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
>     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
>     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
>     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>     at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>     at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.DataReaderSourceAdapter.PreExecute()
>     at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostPreExecute(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100 wrapper)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For I/O intensive workloads you should use Premium tiers. Scale up before running those workloads and scale back to Standard when the SSIS package has finished. Please examine DTU consumption while you run the SSIS package, you may find the workload is hitting the tier limits, and throttling occurs.

Please also set Asynchronous Processing to True. More information about it click [here](http://blogs.objectsharp.com/cs/blogs/cfowler/archive/2010/12/14/migrating-large-databases-from-on-premise-to-sql-azure.aspx). Set Connect Timeout to zero.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I just switched from Ado.Net Data Source to OLE DB. Aside from that I am now using parameterized connection strings. Now my queries are running fine on DEBUG without the 30-second issue. I don't know why though...

Comment: Thank you for sharing with us your findings. Let me try to investigate and share this with more people. If I get an answer I will update this thread.

Comment: Hi Oyen. I think I know now why you are not seeing the same behavior with OLEDB. OLEDB Source has a default connection timeout of zero.

Comment: However with Ado.Net data source, I did increase the timeout but it always, always failed within 30seconds... maybe I can do some more tests myself too.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an option to increase "remote Query timeout" configuration for Azure SQL. As of today no direct information exits, why it is not available in Azure SQL, 
when same is possible in on-premise version of SQL server through sp_configure. My wild guess on this is letting any query to run for infinite time will hinder high availability and fail over architecture promises of MS

Few db configuration settings can be modified in Azure SQL using ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION transact sql. more info can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-scoped-configuration-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

I have an use case of running a maintenance script through SQL JOB every month, which runs for 6 hours in P11 premium and I am pretty sure increasing the premium level to P14 will make no difference. currently this is being executed manually from SSMS. I Keep you posted when I found an option

Comment: Sparked suddenly the remote query timeout is for outgoing connection and it is nothing to do with the server that receives the request. hence increased the remote query timeout of the SSIS server that runs in a managed instance of Azure SQL using SP_Configure proc and it worked